# Get all possible JavaPairRDD key combinations in efficient manner

Tags: java, apache-spark, combinations, scalability

Using Spark, one of the intermediary steps of my algorithm will output (Key, Vector) to a PairRDD. After this step finishes, I'd like to generate all possible 2-combinations of Key's and perform further operations on their values, ie I'd like to have a PairRDD with ((Key1, Key2), (Vector1, Vector2)).

However, I'm not sure how to do this in an efficient manner using Spark - The only way I can imagine is by collecting all key-value pairs on one single machine and performing the combinations on there, which is obviously not scalable.

I'm thinking I might be able to take advantage of one further property of my dataset, though: I only need the combination of (Key1, Key2) to be considered if the dot product of the two value-vectors (Vector<>1, Vector<>2) is non-zero.
(In practice, my vectors are HashMap, and a zero-dot-product would mean an empty keySet intersection)

Any ideas on how I could achieve this in a scalable way? I can't figure it out. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand you want to do cartesian multiplication spark rdd , lucky for you it already provides that function, It will do so without collecting all the data in a single machine but by running on each of the executors.

```
yourPairRdd.cartesian(yourPairRdd);
```

If you want to filter the results where the sum is 0 just use the filter function

```
yourPairRdd.cartesian(yourPairRdd).filter(filterFunc);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! If I understand right, the cartesian multiplication on (K, V), will give me back ((K1,V1), (K2, V2)) pairs, so if I want ( (K1,K2), (V1, V2) ), I'll have to do one (or more) other operation on it, right? That's really helpful though, here I was trying to get the pairs since a few hours by doing huge sequences of weird transformations lol